# building truth-functional connectives

Tags: combinatorics, logic

It is known that $NAND$ and $XOR$ are the only one $2$-argument truth-functional connectives that can be used alone to create every $n$-argument truth-functional connective for all positive integer $n$.

My question is - If I with the only one $k$-argument truth-functional connective can build all $n$-argument truth-functional connectives for all positive integer $n$, then must be $k=2$ ?

Comment: You can always make a 3 argument function that outputs NAND of the first two argument and ignore the third argument.

Comment: XOR is not truth-functionally complete. You mean NAND and NOR.

Comment: Try looking at the class of truth-functional connectives "F" such that F(0, 0, 0)=1 and F(1, 1, 1)=0 and see if any of them work.

Answer (score 1):

Of course if $k<2$, then you cannot build any expression (or circuit) with more than one input, so you need $k\ge 2$.

However, for any $k\ge 2$, the $k$-input NAND or NOR is logically complete. An easy way to see this is to observe that
$$ \operatorname{NAND}(x,y,y,\ldots,y) = \operatorname{NAND}(x,y) $$
and similarly for NOR -- so if everything else fails, just build your circuit out of two-input gates and then simulate each of them with $k$-input ones, duplicating inputs as necessary.

Comment: What does NAND(x, y, y, ..., y) mean?  Or for that matter, what is NAND(x, y, z)?  NAND doesn't associate.  For example, NAND(0, NAND(1, 1))=NAND(0, 0)=1, but NAND(NAND(0, 1), 1)=NAND(1, 1)=0.

Comment: Does NAND(x, y, z) mean the function where NAND(1, 1, 1)=0, and NAND(x, y, z)=1 otherwise?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: I'm using $\operatorname{NAND}(x,y,z,\ldots)$ to mean false if all of $x,y,z,\ldots$ are true, and true otherwise.